# How to create dropdown component with search box in ionic framework with react typescript?

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic4, searchbar, react-typescript, ion-select

Is there any way to customize `IonSelect` component, or to create some custom component which contains search box inside (on top of) it?

There is one ionic component `IonSelectable` for angular and this is exactly what I need in react typescript as well.
Here is link to installation and example: https://www.npmjs.com/package/ionic-selectable for this component. Here is also a link to github repo: https://github.com/eakoriakin/ionic-selectable.

Here is the picture how it looks like, and it is pretty amazing:

[image]

Does anyone know if something same/similar already exist for react typescript? Or, is there any one to create/solve this?

Comment: i have no idea with react but i have created custom modal with selectable search with all select functionality and search data